# Send click event to dialog shown through display dialog command in OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, dialog

I have an sh script that displays a dialog; this dialog can be closed by the user but I am looking at a gracious way to close it, from within another similar script, run at a particular moment, if this doesn't happen. My command is:

```
osascript -e 'display dialog "Hello World! This notification will be closed in the future, due to an external trigger."'
```

The event that should trigger the close is asynchronous, therefore I cannot use the **give up** option.

Is there a way to accomplish this, or should I simply kill the process instead?

Answer (score 0):

The somewhat trivial approach was to create another script, that is identifying and killing the above one:

```
pkill -f "Hello World! This notification will be closed in the future, due to an external trigger."
```

There may very well be a more elegant way to do it...